# I don't understand stack overflow error with repeated DispatchMessageW in the call stack

Tags: windows, delphi, stack-overflow

This is a Delphi application, but I suppose it is a general Windows programming question.

I left my application running (in the Delphi IDE) over the weekend and have just come back to find a stack overflow.

The stack starts like this...

```
:75c4417e kernel32.GetDriveTypeW + 0x23
:75c452ae kernel32.IsProcessorFeaturePresent + 0xa9
:75c45272 kernel32.IsProcessorFeaturePresent + 0x6d
:75c45248 kernel32.IsProcessorFeaturePresent + 0x43
:7678410b KERNELBASE.LoadStringBaseExW + 0xc7
:76678ed2 USER32.LoadStringW + 0x19
:0040c4ae LoadResString + $4A
uADStanDef.TADDefinition.Create(nil)
uADStanDef.TADDefinition.CreateTemporary
uADStanDef.TADConnectionDefTemporaryFactory.CreateObject
uADStanFactory.TADManager.CreateInterface((1050358107, 62550, 16757, (168, 100, 178, 87, 60, 74, 32, 21)),(no value),True)
uADStanFactory.ADCreateInterface((1050358107, 62550, 16757, (168, 100, 178, 87, 60, 74, 32, 21)),(no value),True)
uADCompClient.TADCustomConnection.Create($2DB7EB0)
fMainForm.TMainForm.ServerAliveTimerTimer($2E8DE38)    <========== my code
:004f1546 Winapi + $4F1546
:00461316 Winapi + $461316
:766762fa ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:76676d3a USER32.GetThreadDesktop + 0xd7
:766777c4 ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:7667788a USER32.DispatchMessageW + 0xf
```

So, a timer is expiring, I am creating a new object (of an AnyDac component) and the stack overflows. The code definitely frees the object. I have appended it below for those who want to check, but I don't think that that is my question.

The stack then continues

```
:7669cdfd ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:7669cf5c ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:766cf73c ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:766cfa18 ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:766cfb1f USER32.MessageBoxTimeoutW + 0x52
:766cfd15 USER32.MessageBoxExW + 0x1b
:766cfd57 USER32.MessageBoxW + 0x18
:00549986 Vcl + $549986
:00549aa2 Vcl + $549AA2
:00549873 Vcl + $549873
:00461316 Winapi + $461316
:766762fa ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:76676d3a USER32.GetThreadDesktop + 0xd7
:766777c4 ; C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
:7667788a USER32.DispatchMessageW + 0xf
```

With that block repeated for three thoussand line (!) And I have no idea what it is or what it is doing. It then ends

```
StoreRoom.StoreRoom
:75c4339a kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:77eb9ef2 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63
:77eb9ec5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36
```

I do no tunderstand all of that repeated stack - can anyone advise?

(And for the astutute of you who notice that my exception handling is showing a dialog, that is a TForm which closes when the user clicks OK)

My code:

```
procedure TMainForm.ServerAliveTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
   try
      ADConnection := TADConnection.Create(Self);  <======= stack overflow here
      ADConnection.DriverName := 'mysql';
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Server=' + MAIN_STOREROOM_IP_ADDRESS);  
      // other params, such as password, removed for posting
      ADConnection.Connected := True;

   except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
         ADConnection.Free();
         theDialogForm := TDialogFormForm.Create(Nil);
         theDialogForm.ShowTheForm('Database problem'+#13+#10+''+#13+#10+
                                   E.ClassName+#13+#10+E.Message);    
         StopTheApplication();   <===== just calls ExitProcess(0);
         Exit;                     as I had problems with Halt elsewhere in the code
      end;
   end;

   if isMainStoreRoom then
   begin
      CheckIfStoreRoomIsAlive(SECONDARY_STOREROOM_IP_ADDRESS);
   end
   else
   begin
      CheckIfStoreRoomIsAlive(MAIN_STOREROOM_IP_ADDRESS);
   end;

   try    // Now, update our own timestamp
      timestamp  := GetCurrentUnixTimeStamp();
      ADConnection.ExecSQL('UPDATE server_status SET alive_timestamp="' + IntToStr(timestamp) + '" WHERE ip_address="' + ipAddress + '"');

   except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
         ADConnection.Free();
         Exit;
      end;
   end;

   ADConnection.Free();
end;     // ServerAliveTimerTimer()
```

Comment: +1 for a Stack Overflow question about a stack overflow.

Comment: Why you need to create a connection class everytime instead of using ADConnection.Connected True/False? Do database connection settings change at runtime?

Comment: The question was orignally entitled "I don't understand stackoverflow", but alas someone editted it  (+1 to all likers)

Comment: @pani +1 for the question. The AnyDac folks told me that I must create a new object every time since this is a timer handler which is asynchronous and might execute when other parts of my code are accessing the global conenction

Comment: @Ashish I reverted your edit of the header, stack overflow in the header is an error type, not the name of this site.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Alright. I'm sorry for the wrong edit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your stack overflow is due to `MessageBox()` being called over and over and over in response to a repeating window message.  Internally, `MessageBox()` runs its own message loop, which is obviously processing and dispatching the same message over and over.  That might indicate a timer that has gone astray.  I would strongly suggest you disable your timer when you first enter your `OnTimer` event handler, and then re-enable the timer before exiting.

On a separate note, `StopTheApplication()` should NOT be calling `ExitProcess()` (or even `Halt()`) directly.  Use `Application.Terminate()` instead.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @Remy. I failed to mention that I was runing in the IDE. Could the calls to MessageBox() be from that? I don't call it at all. I do call MessageDlg(), but not in any timer handler - in those I create and show a custom error form. I only have three timers and the handler code for the other two is shorter than the one I posted. I take your point about disable/enable timers, but the shortest (that shown) is 8 seconds. A few d/b accesses can't be taking 8 seconds.

Comment: Wait ... I don't call MessageBox(), but perhaps the AnyDac code does, if there was a database error... but, even then, why would it be looping? AnyDac is well tested by now.  I will give it another run with the timer disable/enable code in and will shorten the timer lengths to try to hasten the problem if it occurs again

Comment: `MessageBox()` may be getting called by `Application.MessageBox()` since it is being called by some piece of VCL code in the call stack. `Application.MessageBox()` is sometimes called by exception handlers, for instance. Hard to say since your call stack does not display the VCL's function names. Are you compiling for Release instead of Debug? In any case, whatever is calling `MessageBox()` is obviously not written to be reentrant and is getting stuck in a recursive loop, pushing more and more data onto the stack with each nested call to `MessageBox()` until the stack overflows.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Remy. I am using XE 2 starter, which might explain the stack as I don't have the VCL source code.  Is there any way that I can breakpoint MessaegeBox() without the VCL sources? (or anything else in that loop)

Comment: What is the timer interval? If this code takes longer to run than the timer interval and there is something calling ProcessMessages, this will be reentrant.

Comment: @GerryColl (+1) the timer interval is 8 seconds. I can't see that being am problem, with one MySql read and one write

Comment: @RemyLebeau - any hints before I go to bed?

Comment: @Mawg - It does not seem to be a problem when it's working, but when failing. Stop the timer at least in the exception block, before the dialog is shown, the app is quitting anyway.